# pushMessage (interact with widgets) from QgsTask

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, subprocess

From my own experience and questions and answers here about QgsTask I understand I simply can't interact with GUI (widgets) from QgsTask in any way (logMessage seems to be an exception) as it freezes QGIS. In particular I would like to use pushMessage, in general turn on/off buttons etc. depending on how is subtask progressing.

Is there a way to push message from subtask? I would expect somehow flag to main process to push message from there? Just can't find any good example of this.

Comment: Have you looked at using the feedback class?

Comment: @firefly-orange Thank you, that looks exactly like something I am after, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach I would suggest would be using custom PyQt signals. The example below is based on the example for [extending QgsTask](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html#extending-qgstask) in the PyQGIS Developer Cookbook, modified to emit custom signals from the background task and listen for them from the main thread. You can then connect to a slot which pushes a message to the message bar or otherwise interacts with interface/gui elements and widgets.

```py
import random
from time import sleep

MESSAGE_CATEGORY = 'RandomIntegerSumTask'

class RandomIntegerSumTask(QgsTask):
    # declare custom signals
    half_finished = pyqtSignal(str)
    number_found = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, description, duration):
        super().__init__(description, QgsTask.CanCancel)
        self.description = description
        self.duration = duration
        self.iterations = 0

    def run(self):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Started task "{}"'.format(
                                     self.description),
                                 MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
        wait_time = self.duration / 50
        for i in range(20):
            # report progress
            self.setProgress(i*5)
            if i*5 == 50:
                # emit custom signal at 50% task completion
                self.half_finished.emit(self.description)
            arandominteger = random.randint(0, 100)
            self.iterations += 1
            # check isCanceled() to handle cancellation
            if self.isCanceled():
                return False
            if arandominteger == 42:
                self.number_found.emit()
                super().cancel()
            sleep(wait_time)
        return True

    def finished(self, result):
        if result:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                'RandomTask {} completed with {} iterations'.format(
                  self.description, self.iterations), MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Success)
        else:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                'RandomTask {} did not complete successfully- '\
                'encountered random integer 42!)'.format(
                    self.description),
                MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Warning)


class main(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lbl1 = QLabel('Task Progress:', self)
        self.prog1 = QProgressBar(self)
        self.lbl2 = QLabel('Sub-Task Progress:', self)
        self.prog2 = QProgressBar(self)
        for c in self.children():
            layout.addWidget(c)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.task = RandomIntegerSumTask('waste cpu', 10)
        self.task.progressChanged.connect(lambda: self.prog1.setValue(self.task.progress()))
#        self.task.half_finished.connect(self.push_message_halfway)
        # listen for custom signal and connect to a slot
        self.task.number_found.connect(self.push_message_number_found)
        self.subtask = RandomIntegerSumTask('waste cpu subtask short', 5)
        self.subtask.progressChanged.connect(lambda: self.prog2.setValue(self.subtask.progress()))
        # custom signals
        self.subtask.half_finished.connect(self.push_message_halfway)
        self.subtask.number_found.connect(self.push_message_number_found)
        # Add a subtask
        self.task.addSubTask(self.subtask)
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.task)
        self.show()

    def push_message_halfway(self, name):
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Task {} is halfway through'.format(name))
        
    def push_message_number_found(self):
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Number 42 was generated- task cancelled!')


main()
```

Comment: very usefull the answered!!! Thanks Ben W